# Is there a better way to store huge text in mssql?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

So I have been reading few articles on whether I should or should not store large text in MSSQL however, all articles that I read seems to be opinionated and there is no concrete answer. I'm trying to build a wiki in Asp.net and each page is around 10000-20000 characters long and I will have more than 3000 pages like that

I want to know if it's alright to keep the text in the DB? will it be slow since the DB is bloated? if it's not, what should I do? keep them in a text file and keep the address there?

Comment: Try nvarchar(max). Depending on your version this is usually optimised.

Comment: That's only 60MB of text data. It will likely be memory-resident in SQL buffer cache. It should be pretty fast with singleton lookups by primary key.

Comment: Hi @PeterSmith and thanks for the reply. Yes, I know I can use nvarchar(max) but what I want to know is if its a proper thing to do? because more than 3000 articles each with 15000 char is a huge thing!

Comment: See comment from @DanGuzman

Comment: As above, let SQL manage the storage for you, this is a much better solution than storing it in a separate file and storing the file path (This is essentially what blob storage does behind the scenes anyway). 40kb per row is not that much (unless you are trying to select all records at once), and using a nvarchar columns means that you can create full text indexes on the data, making searches much faster than looping through files.

Comment: That is not enormous text.  This is still a very small database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` data types to store text. The later is used for Unicode support if needed.

Is it better? It basically depends on what you are going to do with this data. And you have a lot of options depending on your SQL Server version and your hardware - this means you need to (must) test the solution in order to be sure you are using the best technique for your scenario.

If you are worried about the size of the data, you may look to the options of compressing it:

- SQL CLR functions for implementing compression prior to SQL Server 2016 SP1
- [COMPRESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql) and decompress built-in functions are available starting with SQL Server 2016 SP1

If you are going to perform searches on the text, you should check [full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search), too. Or you can create tags and search by them.

Again, if some of the data is not going to be read or modified after some period of time you can archive it. There are different strategies.

You can check also [COLUMNSTORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql) indexes if you are using SQL Server 2017 as `nvarchar(max)` is supported.

Comment: so it's safe to say there is no problem with storing the all the 3000 pages with enormous texts in a table?

Comment: @Ali Sure, it is safe. The engine always it. And of course, depending on your business needs you may need to use or not use some technology of compressing the data, archiving it or search in it.